# Trouble understanding how divs work

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have a div below two floating divs (one floating left and the other right). As I opened up the element inspector I noticed something odd. Why is it that a  div below that with the css property `clear: both` overlaps the top two? Also, when I change the height of the div, the element inspector shows that the div no longer contains its contents. Here are two screenshots to show what I mean. The code is below the screenshots.

No height set in css:
[image: No height set in css]

Height of class "tags" set to 200px in css:
[image: Height of class "tags" set to 200px in css]

[HTML for page](http://pastebin.com/fDhZzBfD)

[CSS for page](http://pastebin.com/A8ighMGg)

Comment: I don't see a 'clear' style on your `.tags` div.

Comment: And the idiot of the day award goes to me. I could have sworn I put it there since it was placing the contents of the div below the other two anyways, but I guess that's only because there was no space left to stick those elements so it just put them below the other two divs. So the size of a div is determined by default by its contents?

Comment: By default, a div is 100% wide and as tall as it need to be to fit the contents. When you float them, the width will collapses to the width of the content.

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors in your CSS. You have some classes inside of other classes which won't work and also you have some unclosed brackets. I fixed it below

```
        #container {
        width: 900px;
        min-height: 500px;
        margin: auto;
        background: #DDDDDD;
        }


        .entry {
        border-top: 1px solid black;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        }


        .title {
        text-align: center;
        }

        .name {
        padding: 0px 10px;
        }

        .tag {
        display: inline-block;
        }

        .link {
        border: 1px solid black;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
        }

        .info {
        width: 610px;
        margin: auto;
        }

        .input-text_area {
        width: 300px;
        height: 250px;
        padding: 0;
        border: none;
        resize: none;
        }

        .input-text_field {
        width: 300px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        border: none;
        }

        .input-button {
        width: 75px;
        height: 50px;
        margin: 2px 0px;
        display: block;
        float: right;
        }

        select {
        float: right;
        margin: 0px;
        }

        .right_half {
        float: left;
        padding: 1px;
        height: 300px;
        width: 300px;
        }

        .left_half {
        float: left;
        padding: 1px;
        height: 300px;
        }

        .tags {
        height: 200px;
        }
        label {
        display: block;
        }

        .text_field {
        width: auto;
        }


        .block-label {
        display: block;
        }
```